# As mining without a pool?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

**Bitcoin 0.14**

Friends, tell me how you can mining without a pool at home on your computer?
I have bfgminer and cgminer
I'm trying to connect so

D:\bfgminer\bfgminer.exe -o stratum+tcp://localhost:18444 -u login-p password

D:\cgminer-4.10.0-windows\cgminer.exe -o stratum+tcp://127.0.0.1:18352 -u login -p password

but it does not work:(

```
bitcoin.conf

regtest=1
server=1
daemon=1
rpcuser=login

# Alice connects to Cory
connect=localhost:18444

rpcpassword=password
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Wait, are you sure you want to mine regtest? You can just do `bitcoin-cli -regtest generate 1` to generate a block. Notice that regtest is a local network that is used for testing, and the coins aren't worth anything.

Comment: Wait, I don't get it. If you are not in a pool then how can you be having a user name and a password?

Answer (score 1):

So Regtest as it says here on official bitcoin Developer notes. https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#regtest-mode

> Bitcoin Core’s regression test mode (regtest mode) lets you instantly
>   create a brand-new private block chain with the same basic rules as
>   testnet—but one major difference: you choose when to create new
>   blocks, so you have complete control over the environment.

Start bitcoind in regtest mode to create a private block chain.

```
## Bitcoin Core 0.10.1 and earlier
bitcoin-cli -regtest setgenerate true 101

## Bitcoin Core master (as of commit 48265f3)
bitcoin-cli -regtest generate 101
```

So on Regtest mode you do NOT need to mine with an ASIC.  It is like testnet but you decide when to and how many blocks to generate for your testing.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT: Old Post below, as missed the regtest part of the config file**

Yes u can solo mine, but you will need to run the bitcoin client so it knows what the latest work is.  I should mention that u should not be solo mining btc without at least 250TH or so hashing power from last calculation I saw with current difficulty, so u would need many ASICs for this.

Otherwise your conf file and connection string look ok.

Comment: I do not quite understand.

Need regtest bitcoin

Comment: Download bitcoin core from bitcoin.org sync the blockchain, then start mining

Comment: Downvoted. This answer doesn't apply to regtest.

Comment: @PieterWuille updated answer as missed the regtest line in the config

Comment: @menfix updated answer as missed the regtest line in the config